# select2 4.0.13 messed up my drop-down options

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-select2, smarty

So am facing an issue when I upgraded my select2 library from 4.0.3 to 4.0.13, what is happening is my countries drop-down options got messed up.

This is my HTML (am using PHP smarty template):

```
<div class="form-group clear">
    <label for="countryselect" class="col-md-3">
          Country
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 countrySelect" style="position: relative;z-index:9999;">
       <select id="country" class="form-control" name="country">
          <option {if $request.country==""}selected{/if} value="">Select a Country</option>
          {foreach from=$countries item=country key=countryKey}
             <option id="{$country.class}" value="{$countryKey}" {if $request.country == $countryKey} selected="selected" {/if}>{$country.name}</option>
          {/foreach}
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how am calling select2 on this select section :

```
$('select[id=country').select2();
```

In 4.0.3 this is the dropdown:

[image]

In 4.0.13 this happened (all options after United States became Mexico till the end):

[image]

Can you please guide me on how to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: check if you don't have duplicated `id` value from `<option id="{$country.class}"`

Comment: @r_a_f Thank you very much, yes apparently all had the class "Others" which caused this issue, it's weird that 4.0.3 accepted it! It's working as expected now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by debugging the id="{$country.class}" and apparently all had the same id which gave all countries as Mexico so i just changed the variable and it worked great.
Just to mention again this was working with the same id in select2 library 4.0.3 but when i upgraded the library it broke it down.

Thanks goes to @r_a_f for pointing it out in the comment.